# C# WPF delegate return object

Tags: c#, delegates, window

I have mainwindow, where is stored `List<>` of some objects. 
Then user can open another window and I need to have access to `List<>` from parent window in this new window, not just in constructor, but from any method etc...

So I created public delegate with return type `List<>` in child window.
And hooking delegate method in parent window like this:

```
+=delegate{ return.List<>;}
```

Whenever I call this delegate in child window I get my `List<>`.

My question is, if `List<>` is copied or if its reference to original one?
I need it to be reference, so I dont waste memory.

Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be returned as a reference to the original List<>. A List will need a very explicit Clone() to do otherwise.

Aside: Your public delegate should be an `event`.

And with an interface or common base class, you could just have used a List<> property .